# IPv6 gateway configuration

Tags: networking, ipv6

I'm running a dedicated server at OVH with 16 virtual machines on vmare ESXI.

The vms are running debian 7.

Network `2001:xxx:2:9508::/64`

Gateway `2001:xxx:2:95FF:FF:FF:FF:FF` according to the [OVH guide](http://help.ovh.com/Ipv4Ipv6).

This is my **/etc/network/interfaces**

```
iface eth0 inet6 static
  address 2001:xxx:2:9508::208
  gateway 2001:xxx:2:95FF:FF:FF:FF:FF
```

If I add the route manually with `route -A inet6 add default gw 2001:xxx:2:95FF:FF:FF:FF:FF eth0` I have v6 connectivity.

What's the problem here? Should'nt the `gateway` in `/etc/network/interfaces` be enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have forgotten your prefix. (For historical reasons Debian misnames this configuration option "netmask".)

```
  address 2001:xxx:2:9508::208
  netmask 64
```